# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'close' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

my code works with chrome, firefox and IE11 only at edge, the new window is opened at maximum size and not closed at all. According to console, the following error occurs when closing
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'close' of undefined or null reference

Any advice?

```
symbolVis.prototype.init = function(scope, elem){    
elem.parent().addClass('doubleclick');
            var url = "";

        scope.switched=function(){
            if(scope.runtimeData.togglestatus){
                //on
                url = scope.config.adresse + "1";
                var win = window.open(url,'_blank','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', '');                      
                setTimeout(function(){
                    win.close();
                }, 1000);
                console.log(url);               
            } else {
                //off
                url = scope.config.adresse + "0";
                var win = window.open(url,'_blank','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', '');                      
                setTimeout(function(){
                    win.close();
                }, 1000);
                console.log(url);
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: Such an off-screen window is probably considered malicious, show the window with a proper size and place it on the screen.

Comment: thats wasn't the problem. i treid it with a proper size and position

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the problem on my side, but the difference is that every thing works well on Chrome and Edge (Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0), but in IE 11 (version: 11.503.17763.0) it will show this error. Please check your browser version.

It seems that the issue is related to the url. If I open the page in my application (the url like: "HtmlPage22.html"), everything works well, but if I open the third part of link such as "https://www.microsoft.com " or "https://www.google.com", it will show this error in IE browser.

So, as a workaround, for the third page link, I suggest you could try to change the popup window url, create a popup page in your application to display the third page (using iframe).